# How to add JS code to the main page of the site to add a number to the cart button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

The following code works well on localhost but not on the main site! Sends only one product number.

```php
       add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
    function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
        if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding <form> tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a title="افزودن به سبد خرید" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="افزودن به سبد خرید" rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
        '<div class="cart-wrap" style="display:inline-flex; width:auto;">',
         woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
         esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
         esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
         esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
         esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
         esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
         esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
        '</div>'
            );
        }
       return $html;
       }
       // ------------------------------------------------------------
       add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );
       function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
      ?>    
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        $( document ).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
            $( this ).parent( '.quantity' ).next( '.add_to_cart_button' ).attr( 'data-quantity', $( this ).val() );
            //alert("Changed");
        });
     });
    
     </script>
    <?php
    }//end: function archives_quantity_fields_script()
```

I **replaced** the following code, but only one product number will be sent again:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1'>
```

Does not work with the following code at all!:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lhja.png

I deleted this part and it was fixed.

```
  data-toggle="tooltip"
```

But I needed it